# How did Fourier series lead to the development of rigorous analysis?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, math-history

Once I've heard that the studies of Fourier series have lead to rigorous definitions of such concepts as function, convergence, integral, limit. And also that Cantor's study of Fourier series led him to set theory. I'd like to know a bit more about it, yet trying to look up impact of Fourier series inevitably brings me to signal processing and alike. Where could I read an account of Fourier series' impact within mathematics?

I've found a few references, e.g. the section titled "The impact of Fourier series on mathematical analysis" in From the Calculus to Set Theory, 1630-1910: An Introductory History (edited by I. Grattan-Guinness) but it wasn't what I expected.

Comment: Take a look at the Historical Introduction Chapter of H.S. Carslaw's *Introduction to the Theory of Fourier's Series and Integrals*. He details the controversy over expanding an arbitrary function in a trigonometric series, and how Lagrange and others were strongly opposed to Fourier's conjectures. Trying to address Fourier's assertions was a key force behind the development of rigorous Math. There's also information in *History of Functional Analysis* by J. Dieudonne about how Fourier's work led to Spectral Theory.

Comment: [Trigonometric Series and the Beginnings of Set Theory](https://xorshammer.com/2008/12/20/trigonometric-series-and-the-beginnings-of-set-theory/). The linked paper is [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/trigonometric_series_and_set_theory_article03.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821829637) by Thomas Hawkins might be what you're looking for.